# What timeout type is meant by net.connect.setTimeout - connection or socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm reading a book and there's the following passage there:

> By default, sockets do not have a timeout. This can be bad, because if
>   the network or remote host fails, the connection sits idle
>   indefinitely. However, you can define a timeout on the socket using
>   its setTimeout() method. This version of setTimeout() takes a
>   timeout in milliseconds as its first argument. If the socket is idle
>   for this amount of time, a timeout event is emitted.

And here is what I've got from reading on the web:

> A **connection timeout** occurs only upon starting the TCP connection.
>   This usually happens if the remote machine does not answer. This means
>   that the server has been shut down, you used the wrong IP/DNS name or
>   the network connection to the server is down.
>
> A **socket timeout** is dedicated to monitor the continuous incoming data
>   flow. If the data flow is interrupted for the specified timeout the
>   connection is regarded as stalled/broken.
>   It is the timeout when waiting for individual packets.
>   It's a common misconception that a socket timeout is the timeout to
>   receive the full response. So if you have a socket timeout of 1
>   second, and a response comprised of 3 IP packets, where each response
>   packet takes 0.9 seconds to arrive, for a total response time of 2.7
>   seconds, then there will be no timeout.

So am right to assume that `net.connect.setTimeout` used on `net.Socket` in `Node.js` is actually a **socket timeout**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick look at [Node.js GitHub repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node) showed the following:

[`Socket.prototype.setTimeout`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/db1087c9757c31a82c50a1eba368d8cba95b57d0/lib/net.js#L318) uses internal [`lib/timers.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js) modules to handle timeouts:

```
Socket.prototype.setTimeout = function(msecs, callback) {
    ...
    timers.enroll(this, msecs);
    timers._unrefActive(this);
    ...
    return this;
};
```

Where [`enroll`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L296) creates a timer without acitvating it and [`_unrefActive`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L109) presumably starts the timer (wow, does it really start the timer now and not when some network IO begins? I don't have Node.js installed but you may want to give it a try).

[`lib/timer.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js) is a linked-list-based timer manager that has nothing to do with socket settings, so yes, I would agree that [`Socket.prototype.setTimeout`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/db1087c9757c31a82c50a1eba368d8cba95b57d0/lib/net.js#L318) is what you call "socket timeout".

Regarding the connection timeout, you can take a look at [`Socket.prototype.setKeepAlive`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/db1087c9757c31a82c50a1eba368d8cba95b57d0/lib/net.js#L356). Keepalive timers are a well-known feature of TCP which you may use to invalidate long-idle connections.